# X Server Freezing using AMD DRI_PRIME

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg

If I use DRI_PRIME=1 after a while the X server will freeze and unable to do anything, not even REISUB works.

Here is my full Xorg log: http://pastebin.com/35JuMD1A

But most of it is useless, here is the actual error:

```
(EE) [mi] EQ overflowing.  Additional events will be discarded until existing events are processed.
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x4e) [0x56498847468e]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (mieqEnqueue+0x253) [0x564988456373]
(EE) 2: /usr/bin/X (QueuePointerEvents+0x52) [0x564988330152]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f139f796000+0x60a7) [0x7f139f79c0a7]
(EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f139f796000+0x687d) [0x7f139f79c87d]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (0x5649882c0000+0x96ac8) [0x564988356ac8]
(EE) 6: /usr/bin/X (0x5649882c0000+0xbfc92) [0x56498837fc92]
(EE) 7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f13ad290000+0x352f0) [0x7f13ad2c52f0]
(EE) 8: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (ioctl+0x7) [0x7f13ad38d067]
(EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (drmIoctl+0x28) [0x7f13ae675138]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (drmCommandWrite+0x1b) [0x7f13ae677dfb]
(EE) 11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_radeon.so.1 (0x7f13a8dca000+0x19c9) [0x7f13a8dcb9c9]
(EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so (0x7f13a8fd6000+0x44247) [0x7f13a901a247]
(EE) 13: /usr/bin/X (0x5649882c0000+0x185b39) [0x564988445b39]
(EE) 14: /usr/bin/X (DRI2SwapBuffers+0x28f) [0x564988446e1f]
(EE) 15: /usr/bin/X (0x5649882c0000+0x1886dc) [0x5649884486dc]
(EE) 16: /usr/bin/X (0x5649882c0000+0x5818f) [0x56498831818f]
(EE) 17: /usr/bin/X (0x5649882c0000+0x5c34b) [0x56498831c34b]
(EE) 18: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7f13ad2b0a40]
(EE) 19: /usr/bin/X (_start+0x29) [0x5649883066c9]
(EE) 
(EE) [mi] These backtraces from mieqEnqueue may point to a culprit higher up the stack.
(EE) [mi] mieq is *NOT* the cause.  It is a victim.
(EE) [mi] EQ overflow continuing.  100 events have been dropped.
```

I don't know to what bugtracker should I report this, or is this even a bug?

I have an AMD Mobility 7970M GPU.

Comment: Which driver are you using? (open/proprietary)

Comment: @user4901968 I use the open source drivers, proprietary don't work at all on muxed GPUs. Here are the packages: http://i.imgur.com/kcU5Asd.png